# Django - Signal receiver not being called

Tags: python, django, signals, django-allauth

I am working on a project utilizing Django All Auth.

Inside the package, there is an `account.signals` file that contains a signal.

`email_confirmed = Signal(providing_args=["request", "email_address"])`.

It is used inside of a model for `EmailConfirmationHMAC`.

```
def confirm(self, request):
        if not self.email_address.verified:
            email_address = self.email_address
            get_adapter(request).confirm_email(request, email_address)
            signals.email_confirmed.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                         request=request,
                                         email_address=email_address)
            return email_address
```

Adding a stack trace in here, I can see it is getting to this part.

Inside my project, I have a python file `receivers.py`

```
from allauth.account.signals import email_confirmed
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(email_confirmed)
def custom_logic(sender, **kwargs):
    a = 0
    import ipdb;
    ipdb.set_trace()
    if a:
        pass
```

However, whenever I confirm an email verification my custom logic debugger is not being hit, the email is being confirmed and the page is being re-routed.

How do I ensure that my `custom_logic` function can be ran, after the signal is sent?

```
 signals.email_confirmed.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                         request=request,
                                         email_address=email_address)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

So the issue was with how I had my signals imported.

Under `apps.py` I added the following:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AuthUsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'auth_users'

    def ready(self):
        import auth_users.signals
```

And then inside my `__init__.py` I added:

`default_app_config = 'auth_users.apps.AuthUsersConfig'`

After that, when I hit the endpoint, the custom logic I was using started working.